# finiteness dimension

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, mathematical-software, local-rings, local-cohomology

$R$ is a *local* Noetherian ring. $f_I(M)$, the *finiteness dimension* of a module $M$  relative to $I$, is defined in `chapter 9 of the book Local Cohomology. An Algebraic Introduction with Geometric Applications` by `M. P. BRODMANN and R. Y. SHARP` as: $f_I(M) = \inf\ \{i  : H_I^i(M)$ is not finitely generated$\}$.
Is there any software that can help to calculate $f_I(M)$ (*perhaps some special ideals and modules*)?
I searched *Macaulay2* and *CoCoA* and I think there is not a direct command for this; but I wonder if there is a technique similar to that *Mariano Suárez-Alvarez* used [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1054354/kta-1-ta-2-ta-3-in-the-form-kx-y-z)?
thank you.

Comment: Is there any chance that $I$ is a maximal ideal (or intersection of maximal ideals).  Then one can do this via looking at some Exts...  (if so I'll explain in more detail).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I can at least explain one way to do this in the case that $I$ is maximal.  Since you are hoping for computers to do this for you, I'm going to assume that $R$ has a (normalized) dualizing complex.

Note that then $H^i_I(M)$ is Matlis dual to $\text{Ext}^{-i}_R(M, \omega_R^{\bullet})$.

Then $H^i_I(M)$ is finitely generated if and only if the support of $\text{Ext}^{-i}_R(M, \omega_R^{\bullet})$ has dimension zero.  In particular, the local cohomology is finitely generated if and only if the $\text{Ext}$ group satisfies DCC.  That's only going to happen if its zero dimensional.

Regardless, this is something that computer algebra systems can easily compute.  Note that if $R = S/J$ where $S$ is regular of dimension $d$, then we also have that
$$
\text{Ext}^{-i}_R(M, \omega_R^{\bullet}) = \text{Ext}^{d-i}_S(M, S)
$$
and Macaulay2 can do this for you.

Comment: It is not quite the $\omega$ of Bruns and Herzog unless $R$ is Cohen-Macaulay, and then it still has a shift.  $\omega$ is a complex not a module though.

Comment: If you are using a computer, presumably you are giving $R$ as a quotient of a regular ring / a polynomial ring (and maybe localized).  $S$ is that regular / polynomial ring.  Macaulay2 can compute Exts.  Look up Ext in Macaulay2.

Comment: @user1, a commuative noetherian ring has a dualizing complex if and only if it is a quotient of a Gorenstein ring of finite Krull dimension.

Comment: In particular, any quotient of a regular ring has a dualizing complex.  Hence a quotient of a polynomial ring has a dualizing complex and any complete local ring has a dualizing complex.

Comment: For what exactly, most of this is basically in Bruns and Herzog.  The more general duality statements are certainly in Residues and Duality by Hartshorne.